# Chrome and Facebook app active content

Tags: facebook, google-chrome

I host several facebook apps. I use active content is some like Youtube videos or google maps. Only in chrome this content is not shown. Also note that it works local but not online.

For example I have a html file with a Youtube video in it. I open it local with chrome and its ok. When i use it as an app I cant see the video.

Could this because of the ssl certificate I have on my server? Maybe chrome does not recognizes it by default. Any ideas of what may cause this?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/myFioreBoutique/app_507973222583457 here is an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution at last.

Chrome does not show content with not secure url. So I replaced non secure scripts with secure.

For example:
- Youtube videos, tick the https option when embedding
- Google maps, include only secure url in Javascript
- other Fb scripts, one quick solution is // instead of http://

Hope I helped some people facing the same problem.

Comment: Nice that you got the solution for your query, could you also accept your answer so people in future may also jump to the accepted answer.